# How to manage Flutter web URL routes using the GetX package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-getx

I am developing a Flutter app for iOS, Android, and Web. I decided to use the GetX package because it makes things much easier, but I am stumped on how to handle Web URL/address bar navigation. For example, one of my screens shows details about an event. Navigating there through the app works fine, but what if I paste in a link to the event in the browser? My GetX EventController manages a `_selectedEvent` event which is how I know which event to display the details for. However, if I use a URL link, my `_selectedEvent` event is never updated and the details screen won't show the correct event.

Currently I set `_selectedEvent` in my homepage when the user clicks on the event to navigate to the details screen. However, if the user navigates through the address bar in a browser, I cannot update `_selectedEvent`. I don't think I can use any of the state managers in GetX because I am not updating widgets, so I am not sure where to update my `_selectedEvent`.

How should I handle address bar navigation?

Hopefully my explanation makes sense. I am still trying to learn Flutter.

Answer (score 4):

Try using GetX named routes with dynamic URL links as described [here](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/route_management.md#navigation-with-named-routes). For example, you could have a URL like 'https://.../events?id=1234' for a specific event, you can obtain the ID with Get.parameters['id'] in your controller and show the event details based on this id.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a somewhat solution if anyone else stumbles onto this question. [This link](https://sellsbrothers.com/understanding-flutter-deep-links-on-the-web) has a good, easy-to-follow description and implementation of routing and navigating with Flutter. It doesn't use GetX specifically to do routing, but I just used `GetPageRoute` instead of `MaterialPageRoute` and GetX navigation instead of the Flutter `Navigator` to still benefit from GetX controllers and bindings. I still have problems with the browser back button, but I think that is a Flutter problem, no a problem of my specific project.